# WPF Datagrid row colour change while row property changed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, eventtrigger

I'm trying to create a datagrid that change the row colour when the row property changed. Below is the code i tried and it doesn't work at all. Any advise is appreciated.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="White" To="Green" Duration="0:1:0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you use Storyboard? if you want just change row color you can use just trigger and mention trigger property and value.

Comment: My objective is to make the changed value's row turn green so it show itself out for user to notice, and turn itself back to white when it doesn't change at the next second

Comment: can you try to set NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True for Columns? like so:

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data1" Binding="{Binding Path=Data1, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="300"/>

Comment: Thanks! That is what I lack of, It totally work! Really appreciate your help!